# In $ \mathbb{Z}[x]$, root $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ $\Rightarrow$ $a\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, roots

Let monic $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Let $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ where $f(a)=0$. Prove that $a\in \mathbb{Z}$

---

**Thinking** the answer below looks alot like the proof of rational root test.

Suppose $a  \not \in \mathbb{Z}$ we can say (a is imaginary or irrationa or rational,not integer...)

Let us say $a\in \mathbb{Q}$. So, $a=\frac{r}{s}$ where $gcd(r,s)=1$ and $s>1$ is a root.

Thanks to the **Rational root test**
$$s\mid (a_n=1) \text{ and } r\mid a_0 $$
$s\mid 1 \Rightarrow s \leq 1$ But $s>1$. Contradition

Comment: It's not true: the root of $2x -1$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$ but not in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Perhaps you meant $f$ to be monic?

Comment: Maybe you meant to say that $f$ is monic?

Comment: Um, $2x-1=0$ . . . (Dangit, Alex! :))

Comment: Maybe he just meant that you'll guess what his homework problem is and solve it for him?

Comment: Haha talk about simultaneous equivalent comments!

Comment: @AlexKruckman It is, in a precise sense, the most simple counterexample!

Comment: @Hugo, what have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please don't just ask us to do your homework for you.

Comment: I appreciate constructive criticism but I am not forcing any one to do something they do not want. I don't understand how some of the comments here have anything to do with solving a math problem. They are useless. You are wasting my time. Your time. Don't you have anything better to do? than to put people down?? Does it make you feel better about yourself??? I really do not understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $a\notin\mathbb{Z}$; then we can write
$$
a=\frac{p}{q},\qquad \gcd(p,q)=1, q>0
$$
Now, if $f(x)=c_0+c_1x+\dots+c_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x^n$, from $f(a)=0$ we get
$$
c_0q^n+c_1pq^{n-1}+\dots+c_{n-1}p^{n-1}q+p^n=0
$$
that can be written
$$
p^n=q(-c_0q^{n-1}+c_1pq^{n-2}+\dots+c_{n-1}p^{n-1})
$$
Can you derive a contradiction if you assume $q>1$?

Hint: if $q>1$, then there exists a prime $q_0$ dividing $q$.

---

This is a variation on the theme of the *rational root test*. If a polynomial with integer coefficients $c_0+c_1x+\dots+c^nx^n$ (where $c_n\ne0$) has $p/q$ as a root, where $\gcd(p,q)=1$, then $p$ is a divisor of $c_0$ and $q$ is a divisor of $c_n$.

The technique of proof is essentially the same and you could try your hand at it.

Your case is the special one where $c_n=1$, so $q=\pm1$ (which does not contradict the above proof, because one can assume $q>0$).

Comment: $gcd(p,q)\neq 1 $ contradiction

Comment: @Hugo Yes, $q_0$ divides $p^n$, so it divides $p$: contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Suppose I have a quadratic monic polynomial with integer coefficients, $$f(x)=x^2+\mbox{[linear stuff]}.$$ I tell you that ${1\over 2}$ is a root of this polynomial. Well, $({1\over 2})^2={1\over 4}$, so we must have $$\mbox{[linear stuff]}({1\over 2})=-{1\over 4};$$ if the coefficients of my linear stuff are integers, why is this a problem?

(If you don't see where I'm going with this, try plugging $x={1\over 2}$ into some specific examples, e.g. $x^2+3$, $x^2-7x+1$, $x^2+13x+12345346$, . . . )